# Package acceptance validation error : Windows phone 8

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8

Package acceptance validation error: We encountered a fatal error while parsing the package CaliPD.xap:

> The file
>   '`D:\data\Temp\3ce7a437-9eca-4eb9-bddd-8397f4e66e8a\Configurables\Images\ApplicationIcon.png`'
>   already exists.. Try again or upload a new package.

I'm Getting above error while Updating package into the store.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Avoided by renaming assets.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate a bit more on your answer? It will surely be more helpful that way.